# Is there a way to combine multiple TextMate windows?

Tags: text-editors, textmate, cyberduck

After files have already been opened in separate windows, is there a way to combine them in TextMate 1.5.9? Or, is there a way to get CyberDuck to open group files edited at the same time as TextMate projects?

If you open a folder of files in TextMate, it groups them all in one window like such:
[image]

But, if I open multiple files separately (as my FTP forces), they appear in multiple windows. Is there any way to combine multiple TextMate windows into one, so they appear grouped like in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 2):

Which FTP application are you using?  If you use something like Transmit's Disk Mode, you can do it just like you normally would.

EDIT: I actually did just discover a way, though it's a bit rough.

1. Open two (or more files) from your FTP application
2. In TextMate, click File - New Project
3. Drag the *icon* from one editor window into the sidebar of the project
4. Close the editor window for the file you just added to the project
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until you have all the files.

Also, here's a screencast: http://cl.ly/37KA

You can also use this simple AppleScript to combine all open documents into a project:

```
tell application "TextMate"
    activate
    set openFiles to {}
    repeat with doc in (every document whose name is not "untitled")
        set openFiles to openFiles & path of doc
    end repeat
    open openFiles
end tell
```

Just paste it into the AppleScript editor and run.  It will leave the individual windows open (I couldn't figure out how to automatically close them) but it should make it a lot easier.

Comment: Cyberduck. Will try out Transmit.

Comment: Depending on how many files you have the solution I just posted might work, though it may get tedious if you have a large number of files.  I do like Transmit though.  :)

Comment: Post-Edit: This actually doesn't work for me. It just transfers an empty file by the same name, but that's likely a quirk of CyberDuck.

Comment: Probably; it works fine with Transmit and with local files.

Answer (score 2):

No. Once you've opened the file you can't combine it into a project. A project (your screenshot) is treated as a separate entity which *can* contain multiple files.

So what you need to do is File → New Project (⌃⌘N) and drag your project items into there. For more on creating/updating projects here's the official documentation:

http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to edit files on your server. If you are serious about working with a whole remote project with dozens of files I can think of three better ways:

1. **Use a versioning system such as Git or Mercurial or Bazaar or Subversion.**

   You work on a local copy of your website/app and commit/push the changes to the remote server when you are satisfied. Git is very trendy these days a bit of googling will return a lot of info.
2. **Use SSH to log into your server and use Vim or Emacs.**

   It's weird. But in a good way.
3. **Mount your remote server on your desktop.**

   There are a number of ways to do it, the most reliable and elegant is [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac) but you can also use [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) or [Interarchy's Net Disk](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/#about) or [Transmit'sDisk feature](http://www.panic.com/transmit/#disks) or maybe (I haven't tried it) [Forklit's Disklet](http://www.binarynights.com/).

   Basically, you have a new icon for your remote server on the desktop and you can do everything you'd do with real local files. Including creating TextMate projects.

   A potentially big limitation though: if your internet connection is slow the whole experience can be painful.